# How to find an Azure instance role size programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-configuration

Is there an API in azure to find the properties of a role (and an instance role)? I'm looking for the instance size, and it is not available in the Azure Management API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VM size isn't exposed in the API, as you've already found out. As suggested by Neil Mackenzie [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazure/thread/6f2bf92a-67b1-4897-a8fa-19f1951336cf), you can call Environment.ProcessorCount from your Azure application, which lets you deduce VM size. You could then store this in an Azure table, for example, and query the table.

EDIT: Here's a screen snapshot where I pushed an Extra-Large instance to Windows Azure and called Environment.ProcessorCount:

[image]

EDIT June 6, 2011 - The Serivce Management API was just updated, including updates to GetDeployment which returns instance size, SDK version, and more. See blog post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/06/06/new-windows-azure-service-management-api-features-ease-management-of-storage-services.aspx) for more details.

Comment: In the [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx) which you have provided, the documentation reads as

Platforms: Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows XP SP2 x64 Edition, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role not supported)

So, will it work for the Azure Environment...? Have you tried using it

Comment: @Naveen - yes, I tried using this, within a Windows Azure compute instance, and it worked fine.

Comment: oh, then how come the documentation specified (Server Core Role not supported). I believe, that all Azure OS are Windows Server 2008 R2...? Are you double sure...? Coz I tried myself and it didn't work out. Anyway lemme check again...

Comment: @Naveen - see edited answer with screen snapshot that I just took a few minutes ago, running an Extra Large instance. I simply called Environment.ProcessorCount.ToString() and assigned that to a textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can get the instance size programmatically using the Service Management API under operations on Hosted Services **Get Deployment**. See this [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460804.aspx) for info.