# Programmatically getting the Instance RAM Size and number of Core for Azure

Tags: azure

Is there any way by which we can get the information of an azure instance.

The basic information which I need are

- RAM Size (Total Memory)
- Number of Cores
- Other essential details of the instance

Comment: this looks like a duplicate of the question you asked here - http://stackoverflow.com/q/4984119/272109 (which I answered for you, and revised with a screen snapshot)- I'd advise editing your other question to include more detail, rather than asking a 2nd time.

Comment: @David, thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. Actually, I am looking for a way to get Server's data from outside as pointed by Gaurav below.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, look in your ServicedDefinition.csdef for the size of server you asked for.  Then compare it to the table [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/compute/).

If it's not your Azure deployment then bad luck.

If it is your deployment, and you don't want to use ServiceDefinition.csdef, then [extract the information as described in David's response to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984119/how-to-find-an-azure-instance-role-size-programmatically) in OnStart() and stick it in a blob named after the role instance ID.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this information from inside your running instances or from outside? I don't think it's possible to find that information programmatically from outside. From inside your application you can probably use Environment.ProcessorCount and combine that with Azure VM sizes (http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/compute/ --> Look under Flexible instance sizes section) to figure out RAM size.

Hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: I need the details from outside. Looking for a way to accomplish the same.